# The relation of Stack, Memory Heap and assembly code

Tags: c++, assembly, stack, heap-memory

I'm trying to understand the compilation process of a C/C++ code and it's memory management in more details. Assuming the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int a = 5;
    int *b = (int *) malloc(40);
    return 0;
}
```

I know `a` and `b` will be created on the stack and value of `b` (memory that it points to) will be on the heap.

The code compiled to assembly will look like this:

```
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movl    $40, %eax
    movl    %eax, %edi
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    movl    $5, -8(%rbp)
    callq   _malloc
    xorl    %ecx, %ecx
    movq    %rax, -16(%rbp)
    movl    %ecx, %eax
    addq    $16, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
```

My Question is;

What does `a is on the stack (memory)` mean here? according the above assembly, `a` is embedded directly into the instruction `$5, -8(%rbp)`, there is no reference to a memory location. If it IS on the memory then what's the address of `a`?

I know `_malloc` creates 40 bytes on the heap (memory) and returns the first memory address but I cannot see how the stack gets populated, there is no interaction with the memory here other than the instructions themselves being fetched form it.

Comment: "$5, -8(%rbp) - there is no reference..." - well, then guess what "-8(%rbp)" is, that's reference to stack area and value `5` is being stored into memory. (it's AT&T syntax) ... memory address of `a` is `rbp-8`. BTW this is everything compiler implementation specific, and compile options specific, so the compiler can decide to compile this in completely different way (but you didn't switch optimizations on, so it's using for-debugging way by default, putting all values into memory where debugger can find them for "watches" window and similar)

Comment: you mentioned `memory address of a is rbp-8`, if I used a debugger like GDB and actually print out the value i will see `0x7ffeefbffac8` as an example. What is assigning this address to `a`? the OS?

Comment: When the process starts, it gets initial stack space from OS (pointed at by `rsp` register)... from there through CRT init code, etc... you will eventually reach your piece of code, where `rbp` is set up relatively to current `rsp` there, and `subq    $16, %rsp` reserves 16 bytes of stack space, where also the `a` will land, so basically yes, the OS assigns address of stack and all the stack-based manipulation then derives from that initial address. (may be different every next run ... also if ASLR is enabled and your executable is PIE, the code itself may be located elsewhere)

Comment: The relative position of `a` to the current stack position upon function entry is then assigned by compiler at compile time, i.e. it calculates that it needs at least 4 bytes for `a`, 8 bytes for `b`, 4 bytes for return value, that's 16 total, then it aligns that to be sure that stack pointer will be aligned as the ABI requires (getting again 16 in this particular case), and so it does produce code doing  rbp=rsp, rsp-=16 and &a=rbp-8 .. that's compile-time task. Where that will land in physical computer memory depends on current `rsp` upon function entry.

Answer (score 3):

> What does a is on the stack (memory) mean here?

It means that the object named by the variable is stored on the memory section called the stack, AKA the call stack. The call stack contains local automatic variables of functions.

> ```
> movl    $5, -8(%rbp)
> ```

`rbp` is the frame pointer. It points to the current frame of the call **stack**. This instruction *moves* the constant 5 to the memory pointed by rbp with offset of -8 bytes. In other words, this instruction initialises the variable `a`, which is on the stack.

> If it IS on the memory then what's the address of a?

The address of `a` appears to be  `rbp - 8` where `rbp` is the address stored in the frame pointer. In the realm of C++, you can use the addressof operator to get the address.

---

None of *stack* (in relation to memory), *heap*, *frame*, *rbp* etc. are defined by the C++ language. These words have meaning in context of the particular CPU architecture.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing in the language which says `a` will be on the stack.  The compiler is entitled to put it wherever it wants; and in particular, if it does not need to put it anywhere, it doesn't have to.

The variable `a` is never used after you put 5 into it, so a decent optimizer would throw that line away entirely.

However, in your particular case, it looks to me like `a` really is on the stack.  It's at -8 bytes off the frame pointer in %rbp.  Which is to say, the address of `a` is -8(%rbp), or "the value in register rbp, minus 8", which is pretty near the top of the stack.

To get more detailed.  The stack exists in memory.  Let's assume stacks grow downwards in memory (this is conventional) so that the "top" of the stack grows towards smaller addresses.  There is a "stack pointer" that points to the top of the stack, i.e., the address of the last thing added to the stack (I'm speaking in generalities here).

To allocate N bytes of stack space, all that is necessary is to subtract N from the stack pointer.  The generated code usually does this in one instruction, since it knows the total space needed for the function being entered.  To deallocate that space, the code can either (a) add N, or (b) restore the pre-subtraction value of the stack pointer, which it had saved somewhere.  The choice is really defined finer details of how the compiler system wants to manage the stack.

There are auxiliary registers that might be employed in stack management.  A common one is to have a "frame pointer", which is the role that %rbp is filling here.

Comment: Then I don't get the purpose of all these namings such as "heap", "stack" and "register". Are you saying to a compiler these are all simply a "space" and "heap", "stack" aren't actually a physical thing?

Comment: @Joe it's quite the other way around, everything is purely physical. if you put some value into `rbp`, you did overwrite particular 64 bits inside CPU, if you will write other value into `rbp`, you will lose your previous one, because there's only one `rbp` register in CPU (well, actually that's not true in modern x86 CPU, but from the point of code logic, it's "only one", the real implementation is "5 layers" more complex, but none of that should be directly observable to running code) ... EDIT: but I think you are expecting Intel syntax, thus not seeing the AT&T memory references?

Comment: Sure the stack's a thing.  The instructions that are manipulating %rsp and %rbp are creating space on the stack,   The stack exists in memory; what makes it a stack is how it is used by software, in a last-in first-out way.  The heap exists in memory; what makes it a heap is how it is used by software, requiring explicit allocation and deallocation.  Registers are distinct things in the machine, generally faster and sometimes having dedicated uses.

Comment: The OP clearly compiled with optimization disabled: that's why the function sets up RBP as a frame pointer at all, and why the local variables aren't optimized away.  (And why the arg for malloc is copied to EAX first, then to RDI, the first integer arg-passing register for x86-64 System V.) `gcc -O0` creates asm for consistent debugging, where every C++ variable has an address, and which can be modified by a debugger when stopped at a breakpoint on any line.